# Access: Append a column to a table that does a true/false match against a master ID list and a smaller one?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm currently developing an email interactivity click table that aggregates multiple sub-tables to develop a full ID interaction profile.  Starting at the base, I need to do a match between a full master ID list that sits in a table (We'll call it **D_Sent**) under the field name of **User_ID** and a secondary table, which contains the subset field of **Sent_ID** in a table we'll call **TBL_SentList**.  *A true match would be equal to 1 and a false or null would be equal to 0.*

It should look something like this (I'm excluding extra fields with the etc.):

```
Table 1: TBL_SendList
Send_ID  |  Name  |  Etc.
1        |  John  |  ...
3        |  Sam   |  ...
4        |  Bill  |  ...
6        |  Jill  |  ...

Table 2: D_Sent
User_ID  |  Email_Send_True <--**This is the column I'm hoping to append**
1        |  1
2        |  0
3        |  1
4        |  1
5        |  0
6        |  1
```

Here is my current idea as to how to solve it in a query to be adapted to an append statement, but there is still an error:

```
SELECT D_Sent.User_ID,
CASE WHEN L.Send_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Email_Send_True
FROM D_Sent S
LEFT JOIN TBL_SendList L ON S.User_ID = L.ID;
```

Thank you in advance - I've been racking my brain around it for a while now.

Comment: What is the error message? This is a query in Access? I don't think Access SQL will recognize CASE WHEN ELSE, use IIf(). There is no need to save this value - calculate when needed.

Comment: It is a query in access.  I think you are right about it not recognizing CASE WHEN.  Ended up eventually using an IIF statement and got it to successfully work without error.  The thing I was having trouble with was creating a matched true/false indicator that eventually gets appended to the table.

Now i have the equation working, but it is appending to the end of my values rather than overwriting.  I'm using an INSERT Statement but should I instead be using an ALTER?

Comment: Use UPDATE if you want to edit data in existing records. ALTER is to change table structure.